# Use variable as key value for FormView Insert

Tags: c#, asp.net

This sounds really simple and for the life of me I can not find out how to do this.  I have a FormView where the user can create a new contact.  I am passing into this page a key variable.  In the insert statement I need to have this key be part of the insert statement.  It is currently defined as a public variable in my cs file but how do I use it as a parameter?  This key does not show up on the FormView.  All of my insert work is done on the ASP page.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have the key value in your code-behind already, just handle the `FormView` [ItemInserting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.iteminserting.aspx) event.  You can access the values being inserted like this:

```
void myFormView_ItemInserting(Object sender, FormViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
    e.Values["columnName"] = yourKeyValueHere;
}
```

Where "columnName" is where you want to put the name of the column that your key value should be inserted into, and "yourKeyValueHere" is where the variable containing your keyvalue should go.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are passing the key variable in the query string, e.g. Page.aspx?key=42. If so, **and** if you are using a data source control, you could simply use the `<asp:QueryStringParameter>` to bind the query string to the parameter declaratively:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID=".." runat="server"
  InsertCommand="INSERT INTO Table WHERE Key = @Key">  
  <InsertParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Key" QueryStringField="Key" />
      </SelectParameters>  
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```